# Google Analytics Reporting API (Python) - How can I obtain previous and next page path?

Tags: python, navigation, google-analytics-api

Using the google analytics portal, i can check the previous and next page path for a given path (for an example, see below) [ Behavior > Site Content > All Pages > Navigation Summary)

[image]

How can I access path of all pages, and then for each of these pages the previous and next pages path via the API?
The API supports ga:previousPagePath, but nextPagePath is deprecated.

Here is a snippet of my source code (python).

```
DIMENSIONS =['ga:date','ga:hour', 'ga:minute', ??, ??]
METRICS =['ga:pageviews','ga:uniquePageviews', 'ga:sessions', 'ga:avgTimeOnPage']

def get_api_traffic_query(service):
  start ='2016-08-24'
  end = '2016-08-24'
  metrics =','.join(map(str, METRICS))
  dimensions =','.join(map(str, DIMENSIONS))
  start_index = '1'
segment='sessions::condition::ga:hostname!~mongo|app|help|docs|staging|googleweblight',
  return service.data().ga().get(ids=PROFILE_ID,start_date=start,end_date=end,metrics=metrics,dimensions=dimensions,
                                 start_index=start_index)
```

Comment: Have you tried some of the page path dimensions ?  https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=page_tracking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [DalmTo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1841839/daimto) mentioned just query for the combination of `ga:pagePath` and `ga:previousPagePath` [Dimensions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets).

```
DIMENSIONS =['ga:date','ga:hour', 'ga:minute', `ga:pagePath`, `ga:previousPagePath`]
METRICS =['ga:pageviews','ga:uniquePageviews', 'ga:sessions', 'ga:avgTimeOnPage']
```

Note: `ga:nextPagePath` is deprecated and returns the same value as `ga:pagePath`. Thus it is up to you to reconnect the flow of `/path1 -> /path2 -> /path3`